# sata drives are not detected in bios after windows 10 install on samsung 950 pro m.2 ssd

Tags: windows-10, bios, sata, uefi, m.2

I just installed windows 10 on a new Samsung 950 pro m.2 ssd. I had disconnected all sata drives prior to the installation. I was running windows 7 on an ssd with 2 other sata hard drives connected (and working) before the windows 10 install.

Once I got everything up and running, I tried connecting one of the sata drives and booting back into the new windows 10 install. Nothing showed up in disk management or device manager. Checked the bios and according to the sata configuration, nothing was connected via sata. The only options in boot menu are windows boot whatever (i don't remember exactly), and Samsung 950 pro. Sata controller is enabled in the bios and set to AHCI mode.

I put the same sata drive into another computer and it was detected fine... For now I am just copying the files I need to a flash drive but I would prefer to have more than 512gb of total space on this computer.

I have a Gigabyte z170x-ud5 motherboard and have already tried updating the bios. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to look at the user manual for the mother board. It turns out when a device is connected to the m.2 port that I was using, sata ports 0-3 are disabled (the ports that my other drives were connected to). I can keep the m.2 ssd in the same spot and will only be able to use sata ports 4, 5, 6 and 7, or connect the ssd to the other m.2 port and only a pci port will be disabled rather than the sata ports.