# Cloned M.2 SSD drive on a Dell E7270 to a new M.2 SSD drive but the new drive is not recognized by the BIOS

Tags: windows-10, ssd, m.2

I have a Dell Latitude E7270 (Windows 10 Pro) with 256GB of M.2 SATA SSD and I replaced it with a compatible M.2 SSD (from Crucial). The only difference is capacity: I used Crucial's website to check specs and bought a compatible 1TB M.2 SSD from Crucial.

I cloned old 256GB to 1TB using [O&O Diskimage](https://www.oo-software.com/en/diskimage-backup-your-data) (Version 12) and I replaced old 256GB SDD with the new 1TB SSD and somehow the BIOS can't see new drive and the system won't boot.

I always use O&O Diskimage on Windows 7 8/8.1 and 10 and up to this point my successful rate is 100% (probably around 30 times for the last few years) on Dell and HP machines (around 5 times).

I have been using same process for *many* Dell Latitude machines but all of them from 2.5" HDD to 2.5" SSD using SSD's from Samsung, Crucial, WD, etc… I always use a 2.5" external enclosure for 2.5" HDDs and SSDs.

This time for the M.2 SSD I used a USB M.2 SATA adapter. The clone process was directly from Dell E7270 using USB adapter. I did same thing but for 2.5" SSD few days ago on a different Windows 10 computer to upgrade from 500GB HDD to 1TB 2.5" SSD therefore I know the clone process works.

Given my success rate, I believe the software is okay. How do I verify the clone worked? Do I need to change something in BIOS?

What is preventing this cloned M.2 SSD from being properly recognized by  the BIOS?

Comment: If you don't have the owner's manual (PDF) you can download it or open it here: https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/latitude-e7270-ultrabook_owners-manual_en-us.pdf You may need to set your BIOS differnetly (See this article also https://superuser.com/questions/1152893/sata-drives-are-not-detected-in-bios-after-windows-10-install-on-samsung-950-pro?rq=1 )

Comment: This isn’t a bad question once you see the details. I have no idea what happened with the other question, but it seems like there is something about M.2 SSD’s and that system. I have edited to make the question more focused and clear. Hope you find an answer.